# use a class from the other child module in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two child modules, A and Util. And I have added the dependency in the pom file of A likes:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>Util</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

With this, I can use the class of Util in module A.

But when I want to generate the jar of A, there is an error of

> `xxx` does not exit where `xxx` es the class of module Util.

I want to know how I can generate the .jar

Update:

The error information is:
[image]

And After I added the dependency, there is not the .jar in the Maven dependencies, it is a file "Util":
[image]

The Util module is :
[image]

I also used "maven install" in Util and the result is:

[image]

The command I used to generate is "`mvn clean package -DskipTests=true`"

Comment: I assume there are errors within your error message - please correct it so that we don't have to estimate what error message you are reffering to. Besides this - what do you mean with "generate"? Do you mean generating a jar by executing `mvn package`? Is `Util` in your maven repository / did you execute `mvn install` in your Util project?

Comment: @NiklasP I have updated mu question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it!

the dependency should be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>AWSTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>AWSUtil</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. What I did this:

Just right click on `maven dependencies` of project A > select `properties` > click on `use maven project settings` > uncheck `Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects`

Eclipse displays that when the dependency is found in the same workspace. You can disable this in maven or project settings, then you'd need to build using mvn to see your dependency jar listed like other.